# Visual Studio 2010: Building toolwindow on the fly in PowerShell

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, powershell

I would like to build a Visual Studio toolwindow "on the fly" from PowerShell code executed in a PowerShell host running inside Visual Studio, with access to $DTE. Any ideas if this is possible in PowerShell, and if so: how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, in order to call $DTE.Window.CreateToolWindow2 you need a UserControl class **in an assembly** ([see MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwtd01y4.aspx)). That's going to make it *very* hard to do usefully from PowerShell -- I mean, you can compile C#/VB code using Add-Type, but there's not much point in involving PowerShell.

You *can* create WPF UI's using PowerBoots as Oisin suggested, but the new ToolWindow stuff really seems to require an assembly.

Comment: If it would be possible using a piece of c# code from PowerShell it would be great as well. We try to do most coding in a way that developers can fix issues on their machines, without having to have Visual Studio SDK installed.

Comment: I wasted five or six hours trying to find a way to make this work, but it seems like you really need the assembly to make CreateToolWindow or FindToolWindow work properly.  I'm toying with the idea of building a "ScriptToolWindow" class as a compiled binary module.

Comment: it wasn't wasted time; you loved it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://powerboots.codeplex.com for building WPF-based UI in powershell.

-Oisin

Comment: I tried PowerBoots. Prefer to use PowerBoots to do extensions within Visual Studio. But I also want the created window to behave like a tool window that can be docked. Would be great to have a piece of code (may be in c# because it is generic) to create empty tool windows that can be used to host PowerBoots controlled WPF into. I do have one issue with PowerBoots, the generation of the classes on the fly, and which assembly to use in which version of Visual Studio. I also had trouble using PowerBoots from a PowerShell 1.0 host we are currently using in Visual Studio. Is not STA.

Comment: PowerBoots v0.2 does not need STA.